# Use only hard tab, only in certain files

Tags: vim

My [vim configuration](https://github.com/volker-raschek/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc) uses the setting `expandtab` to replace tabs with spaces.

For some configuration files, for example the rsnapshot configuration file, I must use tabs rather than spaces.

> Also please note that fields are separated by tabs, not spaces. The reason for this is so it's easier to specify file paths with spaces in them.
>   [rsnapshot documentation](http://rsnapshot.org/rsnapshot/docs/docbook/rest.html)

On my Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian 9.0 Server, the rsnapshot configuration file is stored on `/etc/rsnapshot.conf`.

How I can set up `.vimrc` to use tabs for only specific filename? For example `rsnapshot.conf`?

Comment: What do you mean by "tabspaces" and "whitspaces"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are asking how to configure whether you use hard tabs (tab characters) vs. spaces for indentation, based on filetype, you can do that using autocmd hooks.

For example, here is my base indent configuration for most files. It sets a tabstop of 8 (for hard tab display), and most tabs / indentation shifts are 4, and they use spaces, not hard tabs.

```
set tabstop=8 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
```

However, in some syntaxes that is wrong. For instance, I want 2 spaces in Javascript and YAML. And in Makefiles, space indent is a syntax error - there, I want hard tabs. You can set these things using autocmd and the filetype in question.

```
autocmd Filetype make       setlocal noexpandtab
autocmd Filetype yaml       setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
autocmd Filetype javascript setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
```

If you don't want to specify by file *type* you can also specify the filename (or a glob to match filenames).

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead rsnapshot.conf setlocal noexpandtab
```